# jQuery: Error - matchExpr[type].exec is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was running against this error today. Resources on the internet that could point me in the right direction were very scarce.

Basically, after writing some JavaScript functions, all of jQuery's methods running on selectors would resuld in this error:

```
matchExpr[type].exec is not a function
```

Answer (score 32):

The reason this happened, is because I had extended `Object.prototype`. This breaks all looping functionality in jQuery. Read more here: [Object.prototype is verboten](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/).