# I want to create an extension method to all object or reference that are created using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually, I am currently thinking of creating an extension method to all the object or reference that are created in my component

I know how to create an extension method in typeScript but I am not able to get what I want to use an interface to get the behavior I wanted.

I tried using the Object in the interface but it won't work

**MyExtension Method : extension.model.ts**

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    thousandsSeperator(): String;
  }
}

Object.prototype.thousandsSeperator = function(): string {
  return Number(this).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
export {};
// this is just a simple extension method
```

Now, whenever if someone tries to create an object of class or reference of an interface then, they should get the extension method I created.

```
// Object
Object1 = new MyComponentClass();

// Reference
Object2: MyComponentClass;

this.Object1.thousandsSeperator();

this.Object2.thousandsSeperator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **fooObj** in the below example is assigned to Foo object. so all the
>   methods in the object and the inherited properties can be accessed.

But

> **fooObj1** is just declared as *Foo* type. ie, we are declaring that the
>   **fooObj1** can only have Object of *Foo* type.

```
// Add thousandsSeperator in the Object interface.
interface Object {
    thousandsSeperator(): String;
}

// assign the method to the object prototype.
Object.prototype.thousandsSeperator = function(): string {
    // this is the instance of the object and value is the property on it.
    return Number(this.value).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
};
// now all the object of the created will get the thousandsSeperator method.
class Foo {
    value: string = '123456';
}
// create an object 
let fooObj: Foo = new Foo();
// here on the fooObj thousandsSeperator method can be accessed.
fooObj.thousandsSeperator();

// undeclared variable.
let fooObj1: Foo 
// this is eqivalent to var fooObj1;
```

Comment: it's working for object and what about interface reference

Comment: ya, bro, I know that but how to achieve that for an interface? any logic or suggestions will be helpful

Comment: I got an error
1. function not found for that I refer StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437974/typescript-extend-string-interface-runtime-error  
2. after this I got a new error Uncaught TypeError: V[a].exec is not a function extension method for which I prefer  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063382/jquery-error-matchexprtype-exec-is-not-a-function  
after that, I went to there ans and found out its forbidden to use Object.prototype

Comment: From the first link if you see the string 'translated string' is a String Object. So you can execute string related method on that object.
eg: 'a,b,c'.split(',') => ['a', 'b', 'c']